# Are interpolated scriptures like Vishudh Manusmriti sacred?

Tags: women, manu-smriti, interpolation, dayananda-saraswati, arya-samaj

There has been trend of interpolating scriptures since late-19th century to support feminism/women's equality. The largest example I can think of this is Vishudh Manusmriti by Arya Samaj.

Can such scriptures still be called sacred?